# How to install old version of XBMC on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, xbmc

I'm newbie to Ubuntu so I would be glad if someone can help me out :)

I want to install XBMC 12.03 Frodo on Ubuntu 14.04 I don't know how to do it, I have searched almost in 1 hours now with no luck so I made a account here becouse I saw that many people got their problem fixed by advice from experts , so please any idea ?

I have tried to download by their offical ppa but if I add so then I get the newest version but I want the old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XBMC 12.3 is available in Ubuntu's 14.04 official repositories. Just open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), then run:

```
sudo apt-get install xbmc
```

---

If you added XBMC PPA, you have to remove it before installing. Install `ppa-purge`:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Then purge XBMC PPA:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
```